# How to interpret land use measures in environmental impact papers?

Tags: measurements, agriculture, environmental-protection, land

In reading some papers about the environmental impact of agricultural products such as crops and animal rearing, I am puzzled by the way land use is reported.  I understand that inputs such as energy, water, feed, etc are used up in the production of agricultural products, but land is not really "used up" - it is "occupied".

As such, I expected land use measures to have a time unit, and be reported in some way corresponding to yield, as in area per mass per time - eg, it takes XXha to produce 1t of product / year.  However, the papers I've come across report land use in area per mass, with no time unit specified.  Is a time unit implicit here?  Or does land use refer to something different?

Examples:

- [Williams, Audsley, & Sandars (2006)](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Eric_Audsley/publication/265084052_Determining_the_environmental_burdens_and_resource_use_in_the_production_of_agricultural_and_horticultural_commodities_Defra_project_report_IS0205/links/544e841c0cf29473161be279.pdf): Table I and II - land use reported in ha/t
- [Smetana et al (2015)](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Sergiy-Smetana/publication/279514998_Meat_Alternatives_Life_Cycle_Assessment_of_Most_Known_Meat_Substitutes/links/58c067ba92851c2adfeb0ec4/Meat-Alternatives-Life-Cycle-Assessment-of-Most-Known-Meat-Substitutes.pdf): Table 2 - land use reported in m<sup>2</sup>/kg
- [Tuomisto & de Mattos (2010)](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Hanna-Tuomisto-2/publication/215666764_Life_cycle_assessment_of_cultured_meat_production/links/0e59333858b59f32c3e49e3b/Life-cycle-assessment-of-cultured-meat-production.pdf): Section 3 - land use reported in m<sup>2</sup>/t

Comment: I suppose most crops can only be harvested once per year, hence there is no timescale.